# How can i make the JLabel change through different threads without a final String?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

I know this seems like a question asked and answered time and again, But even after combing through the stack Overflow for hours i couldn't solve the problem. Sorry in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

I need to change a jLable's text each time a Thread starts, and again when that thread finishes. Simply, I'm trying to show the number of threads that are currently running.

`jobQueueView` is a static and final jLabel. `Main` is the jFrame which has the jLabel. `jobQueue` is a static int.

At the start of each thread:

```
jobQueue += 1; refreshQueue();
```

At the end of each thread:

```
jobQueue -= 1;refreshQueue();
```

And finally

```
public void refreshQueue() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().jobQueueView.setText(Integer.toString(jobQueue));
            }
        });

    }
```

This doesn't work. any ideas? Thanks

Edit : As per the instructions of Andrew Thompson
[Swing JLabel text change on the running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578205/swing-jlabel-text-change-on-the-running-application) : on a button click event

[Can I change the text of a label from a Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495337/can-i-change-the-text-of-a-label-from-a-thread-in-java) : has to make the string final. I cant.

[Update JLabel from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895481/update-jlabel-from-another-thread?rq=1) : Uses Timers, I need the thread count

[JLabel on JPanel doesn't update when setText from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370287/jlabel-on-jpanel-doesnt-update-when-settext-from-another-method?rq=1) : Tried the given solutions. Didn't work

[Thread and JLabel in Swing- Not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309808/thread-and-jlabel-in-swing-not-working-properly?rq=1) : More button clicks but different solutions. Still didnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578205/swing-jlabel-text-change-on-the-running-application : on a button click event

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495337/can-i-change-the-text-of-a-label-from-a-thread-in-java : has to make the string final. I cant.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895481/update-jlabel-from-another-thread?rq=1 : Uses Timers, I need the thread count

@Andrew Thompson These are the ones i have open now but i tried more

Comment: @AndrewThompson 5 of 5. Thanks for your help

Comment: *"5 of 5."* Good question. ..sorry, I don't know the answer, but hopefully now the info. is included, it can give people who **can** answer, the context they need in order to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two answers given solved the problem. Here's the final code.

```
public void refreshQueue(int jobQueue) {
        final int jobQueueCount = jobQueue;
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Main.jobQueueView.setText(Integer.toString(jobQueueCount ));
            }
        });

    }
```

At the start of the thread

```
jobQueue += 1; refreshQueue(jobQueue);
```

And at the end of it

```
jobQueue -= 1; refreshQueue(jobQueue);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are creating a new Frame every time.

> new Main().jobQueueView.setText(Integer.toString(jobQueueCount ));

So you have multiple frames but one static label. This may cause the problem. Access the jobQueueView through a static way like below.

> Main.jobQueueView.setText(Integer.toString(jobQueueCount ));

Comment: As per OP "jobQueueView is a static and final jLabel" so how many instances of Main it is creating `jobQueueView` will still be same and will be updated rightly. I agree it should have been used in a static way though

Comment: a single label can only be added to a single parent container. this may cause update problem.

Comment: that can only be clarified, if OP posts full code. might be there is an init method that is called separate from constructor and jlabel got added only once.

Comment: @mfidan This worked, combined with sanjeev's answer below :D Thank you. The problem was me trying to add the same label to the same parent again and again i suppose like you said. Thanks everyone.Ill post the complete code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is, Only final variables are accessible in Anonymous Inner classes from outer classes

So in order to make your code work

```
   public void refreshQueue(int jobQueue) {
        final int jobQueueCount = jobQueue;
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().jobQueueView.setText(Integer.toString(jobQueueCount ));
            }
        });

    }
```

And use it by

```
jobQueue += 1; refreshQueue(jobQueue);
```

And

```
jobQueue -= 1; refreshQueue(jobQueue);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if the problem though as you say the code do not compile

Comment: That is true, you can not use non final members of outer class in an anonymous inner class.